# SmartCard - Select MF succedd but no response

Tags: java, smartcard, apdu, calypso

So I am trying to read my transportation card using what I have learned so far about smartcards.

> My ATR is: 3B 6F 00 00 80 5A 0A 07 06 20 04 01 03 01 F4 1F 82 90 00

when I looked in the `ATR parser` it didn't give me much information.

when I chose the MF file like this: `"00 A4 04 00"`

I got the **response:** `"90 00"`

**output:** but no data.

How can I go on from here to read files on my card?

**Note:** [it would be nice if someone can give me a link to a book or guide about smart cards, cause I found nice one about EMV cards but it is not working on all smartcards]

Comment: Your *select* command does not provide an LE byte, therefore the card must not send a reply. The standard work is Rankl/Effing, Smart Card Handbook, but I'm told, that the English translation has its deficiencies.

Comment: when i set le=00, command=  "00 A4 04 00 00" still got same error

Comment: I have no idea, which error you are talking about, since 90 00 is fine and therefore it is better, when it remains. The more interesting question however is, whether you now receive response data.

Comment: yeah i don't have a clue why this is happens

Answer (score 0):

https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/171-atr-list-full/ shows that from your atr, there are similar cards with similar ATR data.

You can try selecting the dedicated file using the offsets below and see what happens;

0x0002
0x0003
0x2000
0x2001
0x2004
0x2010
0x2020
0x202a
0x202b
0x202c
0x202d
0x2030
0x2040
0x2050
0x2069
0x206a
0x20f0
0x2100
0x2101
0x2104
0x2110
0x2120
0x2140
0x2150
0x2169
0x21f0
0x2f10
0x3f04
0xfeff

hope you can continue from there.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but I don't know what is offset or how I can select a dedicated file using offsets.

Comment: Here is the file structure I you would to try to compare with on that card; https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OB4rnyECsM4JnSKDTFfs5Z_IemRTtikF, from that you will realise that at index the Main File is at index 00, 00, the very firest dedicated file is at an offset of 2 poisitions from the main file vertically. hence, select main file, then find the dedicated file using horizontal and vertical offsets

Answer (score 0):

Select first the `MF` by performing `CLA INS P1 P2 Lc DATA`

```
EX.
CLA 00
INS A4
P1 04 - to select by Name
P2 00 - Select first or only occurrence
Lc - Length of FID 
Data - FID
```